# 2D Line Normals

Tags: math, vector, 2d

I have what I'm sure is a very simple problem but I can't work it out.

I have two 2d vectors that form a line and I am looking to find the normals of this line. example:

vector 1 = ( -10 , 10 ) vector 2 = ( -10, -10 )

How do I calculate the normals for the line defined by these vectors?

Comment: You vectors don't form a line as they aren't parallel. Either you want to connect them through addition and have a line connect from both their end points. Then in that case, you'd get the angle between them through a dot product and the direction of the normal would be half of that angle + the angle one of the vector forms with the reference axis ( I assume, would be X-Axis here ).

Comment: Simply wrong.  There's certainly a line from the end point of vector 1 to the endpoint of vector 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell which "normal" you want.

Do you mean out of the plane that the two vectors lie in?  That's the cross-product of the two.  In this case it's simple: (0, 0, 1) is the normal vector, because both lie in the xy-plane.

Do you mean one of the two normals in the plane for the line that runs from the head of vector 1 to the head of vector 2?  All you need to do there is calculate the vector between them, exchange the values of the x- and y-components, and toggle the sign of either component.

In your case,

```
v2 - v1 = (-10-(-10))i + (-10-10)j = 0i - 20j
```

The normal vector is:

```
   n1 = 20i + 0j  (points in the positive x-direction)

   n2 = -20i + 0j (points in the negative x-direction)
```

Obviously you should normalize these to be unit vectors.

There are two vectors perpendicular to any line in a plane; they point in opposite directions.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I now see my mistake. I was normalising at the wrong stage. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, your "line" is x = -10, and the normal is y = real number.